# Image processing with node

Tags: node.js, angular, image-processing, image-replacement

I am using angular 6. I have multiple images displayed from backend in my web application I want to add some effect on images like increase brightness & cropping or tagging & update that images into the backend is it possible in angular 6 & node?

I am able to change the brightness of image But I don't understand how to replace old image with my new image in the backend.

Comment: Do you want to adjust your brightness like stepper?

Comment: Yes I want to adjust brightness & change orientation if the orientation is wrong & update it into the backend

Comment: [angular material](https://github.com/angular/material2), this would help you set stepper and connect to your pics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use npm package ---->  [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)

> The "JavaScript Image Manipulation Program"
>
> An image processing library for Node written entirely in JavaScript,
>   with zero native dependencies.

Install  --->     `npm install --save jimp`

Answer (score -1):

you can use **sharp**

It is High-performance Node.js image processing, the fastest module to resize JPEG, PNG, WebP, and TIFF images.

```
npm install sharp
const sharp = require('sharp')
```

link to Github page